# MoSync experiences

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cross-platform, symbian

Does anybody have experiences from cross platform mobile app development framework [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)?
It sounds very good and promises much. But does it deliver?

Comment: The only problem is that it's not available for Linux platform users.

Answer (score 14):

We have used MoSync for 8 months now and I have a good feeling about it. It is still magic to me that you code in C++ and out comes a jar-file or whatever platform you choose.
It is great for application development but I wouldn't recommend it for gaming with advanced graphics. It seems too slow for that on Symbian.

The APIs are very easy and I learned it very fast. And I have the freedom to do whatever components I want thanks to the MAUI framework and using widgets with skins. You can really make an application look very nice.

It is great for me as a developer that I can support so many phones and platforms. I can also do specific behavior and include/exclude functionality based on the phones capabilities.

When it comes to deployment I end up with hundreds of binaries for every device and I have to take care of them my self. To put them on a web server somewhere and make sure that every user get the correct binary when they try to download the app. I wished that they had some kind of app-store so they could host the apps.

MoSync still have a bit to go until it is working properly. There is no guaranty that an application that is build for a specific device actually works on that device. But I'm sure that they will reach there very soon. And when they do... I simply just need to rebuild my app with the SDK (I think).

Comment: "It seems too slow for that on Symbian": I don't doubt that, but just to balance that comment a bit, according to a simple test of an evaulation app the MoSync version launched really fasy compared to other cross-platform development frameworks. Not sure how good of a measure that is though? See http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6178193

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Mosync 2.6, I think this solves most of the problems you mentioned,
the feature list is at:

http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/whats-new-mosync-26-pyramid

I personally I'm quite excited about the whole HTML 5 integration, it sort of blurs the line between native and web app.

Hope this Helps

Tony